# How to hide <br> tags in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm sure it's an easy answer that I'm missing, but I've been staring at this for hours now... thanks in advance.

Here is what I have:

```
function handle(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that runs
        var txt;
        var b = "<br>";
        txt = document.getElementById("enteredText").value;
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = txt + b + "\n";
        document.getElementById("enteredText").value = txt + b + "\n"; 
    }
};
```

The output of text.innerHTML ONLY puts in the breaks when the 
 tag is physically put into the textarea. How can I get it so that it will put the 
 tags into the text area, the text.innerHTML will display it properly?